# CSS drop down sub-menus vertical alignment

Tags: css, html

I have a drop down menu at https://admin.vybenetworks.com/vybe/dropdown/ which works fine except for one thing.  The sub-menus are aligned to the top of the navigation rather than to the menu item that it is part of.  For example, under "Billing" there is a sub-menu called "Reports" with one item called "Sales Report".  The sub-menu is displaying up near the "Recurring billing" item instead of next to the "Reports" one.

I tried searching for this issue but few hits were actually about this issue.  I think that the containing element (LI) is "position: relative" and the sub-menu (UL) is "position: absolute" but it always puts it relative the the parent UL instead.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: just to be clear, on the example you state that under 'Billing' you can find 'Reports' - which should be a submenu but it is not - and under 'Reports' you should find 'Sales Reports'. Am I understanding you well?

Comment: That's correct.  The "main" menu is the one across the top which includes "Billing."  Hovering over it brings up a submenu which includes "Reports" as the last item.  Hovering over that brings up a submenu with one item , "Sales report."  The problem is that this last one is up at the top and it should be beside "Reports" so that you can mouse over to it and select it.

Comment: In your Vybe.css file, on line 286, on your nav ul ul ul you have a 'top' property, which is currently set to 30px, try changing that to 252px and let me know what you think

Answer (score 0):

In your Vybe.css file on line 286px, you have an element like so: nav ul ul ul. Change the property top of this element to:

```
nav ul ul ul {
    /* other code here, don't copy this comment */
    top: 252px;
    /* other code there, don't copy this comment */
}
```

It will make the sub menu element slide down next to it's corresponding parent. You can modify as you seem fit but I think 252px is spot on.

Let me know if that worked/did not work for you.

Comment: I have to say, "no."  It might place that one menu where I want it but I really wanted a generic solution.  I don't want to micro-manage my own page.

Comment: I understand, I wrote my solution within 2 minutes of leaving for my evening commute back home. I will give you a more complete solution tomorrow unless someone else can help you... sorry for the delay. Make sure to upvote/accept answer if you find anything helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS file Vybe.css, update following things,

```
NAV UL UL LI {
  border: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
NAV UL UL UL {
  left: 105%;
  top: 0;
  border-style: none;
  width: 195px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

`float:none` replaced with `float:left`, `left:100%` replaced with `105%` and `top:30px` replaced with `top:0`

Comment: Yes!  Perfect.  Now I just need to figure out why it works.  I must confess that the float tag sometimes confuses me.  I understand the left and top adjustments.  They're obvious once the float:left was added but why does that work?  I even tried float:right and it worked just as well.

Comment: `float` tag can be used to create entire web layouts. Floated elements remain a part of the flow of the web page. In your case, when you used `float:none`, the `LI` elements cudn't get their space in the layout, as a result the child sub `UL` positioned themselves relative to the main `UL` instead of the `LI` element.